# What Would Cause two DIVs (display:block;width:100%) to Overlap?

Tags: html, css

What in the world could cause a DIV (display:block; width:100%) to overlap the DIV (display:block; width:100%) that follows it?

Because I can't get mine to stop doing that.
(I put all the code below. Removed all css style sheets. 
Replaced it with inline style attributes)

I wish I could post a screen shot, because I coded it to make it all obvious ... that's why the blue banner writes its text right justified and green container writes left. And it's really clear on the screen.

NORMALLY the code would render:

--- A thin blue background div (display:block; width:100%)

--- A green div (display:block; width:100%) that contains two child div (display:block; width:100%)

--- Another thin blue background div (display:block)

My problem is that while the thin blue divider that follows the container block, renders normally, the first one

a) drops it's blue background color, and

b) writes its text over the top row of the GREEN container that follows it.

```html
 <!--  include leaves <div class='content-block'> unclosed -->
    
    <!-- This is just a DIV (display:block;width:100%) 
         I use to render a solid blue divider across page --> 
    <div style="display:block;
                background:#002868;
                width:100%; 
                height:2em;       
                color:white;      
                font-size:16pt;  
                font-weight:bold; 
                text-align:right;">    
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     AND I'M SUPPOSED TO BE IN BLUE BANNER
    </div>
    
    <!-- This block just contains two 100% blocks 
          I've cut it's text content to one line of text-->
    <div style="display:block;
                background:green; 
                padding:2em;
                color:white;      
                font-size:16pt;  
                font-weight:bold;">
      I'M GREEN DIV BLOCK #0
        <!-- first child block -->
     <div style="display:block; 
                 background:#9a4569;  
                 height:3em;
                 color:white;      
                 font-size:16pt;  
                 font-weight:bold;">
       I'M DIV BLOCK #1 IN BURGANDY LINE
     </div>   
        
        <!-- second child block -->
       <div style="display:block; 
                   background:pink; 
                   height:3em;
                   color:white;   
                   font-size:16pt;  
                   font-weight:bold;">
         I'M DIV BLOCK #2 IN MY PINK LINE
        </div>    
    </div> <!-- closes GREEN  container -->
    
    <!-- another thin blue divider -->
    <div style="display:block;
                background:#002868;
                width:100%; 
                height:2em;       
                color:white;      
                font-size:16pt;  
                font-weight:bold; 
                text-align:right;">
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         AND I'M SUPPOSED TO BE IN BLUE BANNER
    </div>
    <!-- rest of page -->
    <!-- this closes content-block div above-->
```

Comment: The code you provided render everything as expected

Comment: You should use the style element instead of the attribute, for cleaner and maintainable code

Comment: I do know that.  I only attributes instead of a css file to simplify posting.  (Any way to post a screen shot, because this code does not render correctly where it is.  Just won't.)  So there is something about it's multiple parent containers that's forcing the wrong rendering.  Therefore,  what I really need to know is whether anyone knows of  anything that would cause this code to result in a div block writing over the following one????  Because if this works by itself ... I need to look higher ... and don't know what to look for.